# Possible to Drag Shapes Within a GridPane with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop, shapes, gridpane

Am I correct in thinking it is not possible to drag Shapes within a GridPane? Here's a link to some code that allows the user to drag shapes around the screen: [Drag and Drop Shapes](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX_How_to/Shape/Handle_Shape_drag_and_drop_events.htm)

I want my shapes to have the same behavior as above, but I want them in a GridPane (eventually I'd like their movement to be locked to the X or Y axis to be moved on to adjacent shapes).

I added the below code to the "start" method. It creates circles using the same method as the example code but instead adds them to a grid. Surprisingly, this *removed* the ability for them to be dragged around.

```
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
grid.setLayoutX(300);
grid.setLayoutY(100);

int n = 3;
int m = 3;
for (int r = 0; r < n; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < m; c++) {

        Circle circle = createCircle(100, 50, 30, Color.BLACK);
        grid.add(circle, c, r);
    }
}
root.getChildren().add(grid);
```

If you want to test this just add the above code to the "start" method of the example code, just above these lines:

```
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

My theory is the GridPane, because it locks the circles to certain positions, doesn't allow this dragging behavior.

Any input on how I can achieve movement of the circles along the X and Y axis when dragged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, layout panes such as `GridPane` manage the placement of their content. Changing the layout coordinates will not affect nodes that are placed in these panes. You may find it better to use a plain `Pane` and manage the layout yourself for functionality such as this.

If you do want to use a `GridPane`, transformations (such as translations, etc) are applied *after* layout coordinates are computed, so you can use a translation (e.g. the one built-in with the `translateX` and `translateY` properties) to manage dragging in a layout pane.

So you can do:

```
circle.setOnMouseDragged((t) -> {
  double offsetX = t.getSceneX() - orgSceneX;
  double offsetY = t.getSceneY() - orgSceneY;

  // No idea why they are doing this. c is just circle
  Circle c = (Circle) (t.getSource());

  c.setTranslateX(c.getTranslateX() + offsetX);
  c.setTranslateY(c.getTranslateY() + offsetY);

  orgSceneX = t.getSceneX();
  orgSceneY = t.getSceneY();
});
```

Comment: where is orgSceneX & orgSceneY defined here?

Comment: @SiddharthDinesh In the code in the link in the OP.